# Black Screen With Cursor on Logout in Yosemite

Tags: macos, mouse, remote-desktop, user-account

This is specifically occurring on Yosemite Macs that have been NetRestored. Initial login works fine. However, when restarting the Mac or logging out of the user, a black screen appears with only the mouse cursor there. (Please note this is on logout, not login. I'm quite familiar with the login issue.)

I cannot even get out of it by sending a Restart (Lose Changes) command through ARD. Only a manual force shut down solves the issue.

In the past, I've removed the /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist file and it's solved the issue. However, it's still occurring now. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does [verbose mode](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201573) give any clues?

Comment: How long did you wait? I've seen an issue that can make your computer take about two minutes to shutdown. Also, there is a slightly safer force restart by pushing `command + ctrl + power button`. More advisable.

Comment: Sadly, verbose mode didn't really help here. And I left a Mac sitting there for 30-45 minutes. In the end, I destroyed the LoginWindow.plist and that seemed to resolve the issue.

Comment: Used to be I could SSH in when this happened and kill `loginwindow`; lately that's not even working and I think I'll need to do a full restart.  Driving me *crazy*.

Answer (score 4):

Just returned here, although old question, to leave the solution I have found  after long suffering this problem in High Sierra after trying to upgrade from version 10.13.5 to 10.13.6. I deleted these files through terminal, then rebooted.

You may need to enter your admin password when asked:

```
sudo rm -f /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist
sudo rm -f /private/var/db/.AppleUpgrade
sudo rm -f /private/var/db/.SoftwareUpdateAtLogout
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Had the same problem after updating to macOS Mojave... This fixed the issue. Thanks

Comment: Formatted disk, reloaded macOS, restored TimeMachine: Problem came back.
Found this, deleted the files, fixed. Thanks!!
There was no .AppleUpgrade file, but deleting the other two fixed it.