# After reinstall macOS 10.13.6, App store not work with updates

Tags: mac-appstore, software-update, restart

Simple.

- Opened App Store
- Updated software
- Stuck. Now my computer not restart.

Now the only way to restart my computer is via terminal

[image: App Store]

Comment: can you clarify?

Comment: If it doesn't restart after you click restart, have you tried restarting manually?

Comment: Clarify? Is simple. Click on Retart, not restart. Go to menu Apple -> Retsart and not restart. Just installed fresh system 10.13 from Apple, format hard disk (after 10 years without formating) and now Diosk has a APFS disk system. I don't more information for issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't my new MBP actually shutdown when I click "Shutdown..." in the "apple" menu](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352117/why-wont-my-new-mbp-actually-shutdown-when-i-click-shutdown-in-the-apple)

Comment: Not duplicate beacuse, my computer no go to "sleep mode", not "blank screen"... only "dont restart" only "no go to restart"