# Macbook Pro never shuts down

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power

I've got a Macbook Pro 2020 13 inch (10th gen CPU) and I can't get it to shut down so it won't consume any energy. Methods I used are:

(1) Hold down power off button (top right) for a long period of time -> MBP seems to shut down (keyboard/back lights off), but I can tell it's still active (10% battery loss after a couple of days; trackpad is still responsive (tactile feedback))

(2) I've done (1) in safe mode, same result

(3) I've done this via the Apple -> Shut down menu item (same result)

(4) I've closed the lid and opening it does not turn on the computer, but clicking any button or the trackpad does.

I'd like to either shut down the MBP completely, or even better close the lid and turn it to (real) hibernate (suspend to disk/no wake ups in between until I need it).
I'm at a loss here, if anyone has a MBP can you please try to completely power it off and provide feedback?

Comment: What happens when you out the command `sudo shutdown -h now`?  Does the Mac turn off then?

Comment: Same effect - that's method (5) I tried (forgot to mention it). Just to be clear - there is no app installed on the Mac, it's been restored (disk wiped, macOS reinstalled). Is anyone experiencing the same (i.e. that they can't shut down their MBP at all???)

Comment: I’ve never even heard of this much less experienced it.  It’s piqued my curiosity, though.

Comment: It's insane - Apple support tells me that this is a feature and expected behaviour...

Comment: To *never* shut off?!?  That’s going to be interesting when someone has to go into a secure government building that has high security areas.  I went to SOCOM once and in this one area all devices had to be secured (left with security and turned off). I’d love to be there when someone tells military security “can’t turn it off is a feature”

Comment: ... or on an aeroplane ... it's gotta be a hardware defect, surely.

Comment: I found this related thread: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352117/why-wont-my-new-mbp-actually-shutdown-when-i-click-shutdown-in-the-apple